# Make SwiftUI document available as EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am reading a `FileDocument` using SwiftUI. This document is available though a binding to the top-most view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: SomeDocument
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.document.someString)
        NestedChildViews().environmentObject(self.document)
    } 
}
```

Is there are a way to turn this `@Binding` of the document into an `@EnvironmentObject` to make it available to all nested views? Simply replacing `@Binding` with `@EnvironmentObject` will not work, since `FileDocument` is a struct.

```
Property type 'SomeDocument' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'EnvironmentObject'
```

Creating an in-between `ObservableObject` that is created as a `@StateObject` inside `ContentView` won't work, since it has to be initiated before the Binding to document is available:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: SomeDocument
    @StateObject var sharedState = SomeSharedState(document: self.document) // won't work
}
```

What would be the best way to handle this in-between a document and a series of nested views without passing bindings between all levels of them?

Comment: what is SomeDocument and where it data come from?

Comment: Make sure `SomeDocument` conforms to `FileDocument` instead of `ReferenceFileDocument`. This will mean that your document is value based instead of reference based. After that you should be able to use `@Binding`.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your `@StateObject` from within the view's init, since you are passing in the `document` into the init:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Binding var document: SomeDocument
    @StateObject var sharedState: SomeSharedState
    
    init(document: Binding<SomeDocument>) {
        _document = document
        _sharedState = StateObject(wrappedValue: SomeSharedState(document: document.projectedValue))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(document.someString)
            .environmentObject(sharedState)
            
            /* TEST TO SHOW IT WORKS
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                    document = SomeDocument(someString: "New!")
                }
            }
            */
    }
}

class SomeSharedState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var document: Binding<SomeDocument>
    
    init(document: Binding<SomeDocument>) {
        _document = Published(initialValue: document)
    }
}
```